# Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) using windwos 7 (no rvm)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, production

people,

I'm new to ROR, not bloody new (anymore) but unexperienced with moving apps to production. To understand how the move-to-production-flow works I created a very simple rails project. Here are some basic infos about my system (running on windows 7):

```
Ruby version                1.9.3 (i386-mingw32)
RubyGems version            1.8.24
Rack version                1.4
Rails version               3.2.8
JavaScript Runtime          JScript
Active Record version       3.2.8
Action Pack version         3.2.8
Active Resource version     3.2.8
Action Mailer version       3.2.8
Active Support version      3.2.8
Application root            C:/Sites/railstest
Environment                 development
Database adapter            sqlite3
Database schema version     0
```

Middleware:

```
ActionDispatch::Static
Rack::Lock
#<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x2a70f20>
Rack::Runtime
Rack::MethodOverride
ActionDispatch::RequestId
Rails::Rack::Logger
ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
ActionDispatch::Reloader
ActionDispatch::Callbacks
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
ActiveRecord::QueryCache
ActionDispatch::Cookies
ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
ActionDispatch::Flash
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
ActionDispatch::Head
Rack::ConditionalGet
Rack::ETag
ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport
```

My webhost is webhostone.

**And here is what I did:**

1. Generate a new rails app called railstest using: rails new railstest
2. Updated the gemfile with the versions used on my webhost
3. run "bundle install --deployment" to have all the gems in vendor-directory.
4. FTP'ed everything to the webhost
5. successfully run bundle install via PuTTY

But when I call the site I always get something like this:
http://www.kernification.de/rails/info/properties
(I don't have enough reputations to post an image here...)

I've tried a lot more (I'm fighting for ~1.5weeks now with this issue) but it seems to be the same issue all the time. The webhost support told me the gems are located in 1.9.1, not in 1.8 and I have some questions about this:

1. What is 1.9.1 (or 1.8) the version of? Ruby? Gem?
2. How do I force to look for the gems in 1.9.1 instead of 1.8?

I also tried using pik as version manager but I will only use webhostone so far, so I happy if I have one version of ruby installed that is working. So far I don't need to switch between any versions. I also moved to xubuntu, created the same simple app there, same result.

Would be great if you could share your experience, thanks a lot!

Comment: Additionally I would recommend to use SCP or SFTP instead of FTP to transfer your application onto the deployment server. Both provide encrypted file transfer to an cryptographically authenticated SSH server.

Comment: Update:
Today I removed rails and took a railsinstaller that gives me the same versions like on the prod. server:

**Server:**
'$ rails -v'
'Rails 3.2.8'
'$ ruby -v'
'ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i486-linux]'
'$ gem -v'
'1.8.24'

**Local Windows:**
'C:\Sites>rails -v'
'Rails 3.2.8'
'C:\Sites>ruby -v'
'ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]'
'C:\Sites>gem -v'
'1.8.24'

The issue is still similar, production rails is looking in ...gems/1.8/... instead of ...gems/1.9.1/... for the gems.

Comment: please check your GemFile for more details. the errors look like the gems are located in 1.8 and for Ruby1.9.3 it should be in 1.9.1 directory

Comment: Here is what I get from gem environment: **Server:** GEM PATHS: - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 - /home/.gem/ruby/1.9.1 **Local Windows:** - GEM PATHS:- C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 - C:/Users/scs/.gem/ruby/1.9.1 Looks like both are using 1.9.1.

Comment: Check GemFile.File in your application directory.

Comment: Checked, I only have specified the gem versions that are available on production server. Nothing found with 1.8. I also searched the whole app dir for 1.8 (also in files) and only found it for the jquery revision but not for gem related stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a call with my webhost support and it looks like the issue was related to the apache configuration. It is still not fixed but the issue described above is gone. Now there is a new issue but this is a different story and I will search in this really great forum first.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The version numbers you listed match Ruby versions. It is possible to tell Rubygems where to look for the local gem repository through setting the GEM_HOME environment variable. But this is probably not what you want to do, as Bundler should provide all the gems.

By calling `bundle install --deployment` all gems your application needs should be bundled within the `vendor/bundle` directory. Therefore I don't understand why you call `bundle install` again on the deployment site.

You could check if your application folder on the deployment server contains the `rake` gem bundled into `vendor/deploy`.

Comment: Hi aef,
Thanks for your reply! There is no special reason why I run bundle install on deployment site expect the fact that it didn't work without and I had no better idea than to try bundle install...
Good hint to check the vendor directory. I found
rake-0.9.2.2
in
railstest\vendor\bundle\ruby\1.9.1\gems\,
so looks ok so far.